# Putting a splash screen on a timer in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, timer, splash-screen

I saw from looking through similar questions that splash screens are not generally liked or advised, but I am in a java class and our prof wants one when we start our project and to be on a timer for a few seconds.

I know from previous projects in NetBeans I can right click/properties the project name and go to RUN and post this in the VM OPTIONS window:

```
-splash:src/splashScreen.jpg
```

But I need to put this one on a timer.  Is there a code I can add to that portion or do I have to write it into the java class after `initComponents();` ?

Comment: How did you make it show in the grey background when it the words you are writing are code Romania?  Thanks for the edit... i think?  :)

Answer (score 0):

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Create a Splash Screen](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html). The working example shows how to close the splash screen after a specified time period.

> or do I have to write it into the java class after initComponents();

I have never used Netbeans, but that would be my guess. Give it a try. You can read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for basic info on using a Timer.